# Regex help matching string

Tags: php, regex, string

Looking for a bit of regular expression help using `PHP`. What is the `regex` for the following:

```
EXACTLY {{file: THEN 24 characters from a-zA-Z0-9 THEN EXACTLY }}
```

Example:

```
{{file:504c2ee3ff558cb40700000b}}
```

Looking to match that pattern. Thanks much.

Comment: And please show what you've tried so far, and how it fails to do the task you're after.

Comment: Really you should say what programming language you are using.  Regular expressions differ in the fundamentals and in the details between languages.  I'm sure once you tell us it's easyBasic or Q# you will get a quick answer.

Comment: @LinusKleen the language is `PHP`. Thanks.

Comment: `^\{\{file:[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}\}\}$` should do it in most RegEx dialects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match_all('/\{\{file:[a-zA-Z\d]{24}\}\}/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `preg_match_all('/\{\{file:[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}\}\}/i', $str, $matches);`

Comment: @Justin The `i` modifier means case insensitive, So you don't need to write `A-Z`

Comment: The `i` modifier would make the "file" part case insensitive, as well.

Comment: personally I would spell out A-Z rather than rely on /i - which looks a bit hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
preg_match_all('((\{{2})file:([a-z0-9]){24}(\}{2})/i', $str, $matches);
```